# MySQL crash, after rebooting cannot access mysql and low screen resolution

Tags: mysql

I am stuck and need help please.  I am a non-expert user and struggling with a crash yesterday.  I was running an R script in Rstudio that was accessing data locally from mysql, and Rstudio hung.  I tried closing/ending without luck so turned off the power switch. When I rebooted the screen resolution has changed to a much lower one with no option to change it in Display. More worrying, I am unable to access mysql from the terminal using:

```
$ mysql -u root -p
```

I get the following error:

```
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

After some googling, I tried doing a Memtest from advanced options when booting - reached Test 6, 25% then I stopped it.

I also tried the disk check from booting from a USB and it did not find any errors.  I have no idea what is wrong.

I am on Ubuntu 14.04

Kernal log:
[Kernal log](http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/12726571/)

Syslog:
[Syslog](http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/12726590/)

Comment: Perhaps unrelated but: `WARNING: mysql.user contains 4 root accounts without password!`

Comment: Should i remove the 4 root accounts and how to do so?

Answer (score 0):

That last bit isn't uncommon I believe, depending on what you use mysql for. It's probably some entries for specific users which only allow entries from the localhost. I don't know about the RStudio so can't help with that.

The screen resolution implies an upgrade to the video drivers  already done, has been corrupted during the crash. How you resolve that depends on the make and model of video card.

I do use mysql for my mythtv setup but I'm no expert, tbh, so I hesitate to respond but there's some stuff here...

https://superuser.com/questions/603026/mysql-how-to-fix-access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost

Comment: Thanks for sharing the link, will check it out. I hope my mql data is in tact. So its okay to leave the root accounts? Also what to do about the video drivers?

Comment: I use mysql for mostly numerical data that i analyse with R. There is a massive quantity of data with over a thousand tables. The R scripts make mostly select and write SQL statements.

Comment: I'd always change the root password anyway just as a matter of good practice. I'd check out http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/mysql-change-root-password/ or similar for how. I was just saying if connections are only allowed from the localhost/127.0.0.1 it's probably not as significant.

Comment: Video driver depends on your graphics card. You need to provide us with more information.

Comment: Thank you.  The processor and graphics card is Intel - Xeon E3-1225, graphics Intel Haswell Server.

Comment: I just completed the steps for resetting the mysql root password as per your link.  I'm now able to access mysql from the terminal, but none of my previous databases are showing.  It's like a fresh install of mysql or something.  Any idea what is going on?

Comment: Do you mean when you type 'show databases;' at the mysql prompt? It should show at least the mysql database and the information_schema. Is that what you mean? If so and your other databases are completely missing it might be worth asking on a specialised mysql forum as, in the absence of anyone more expert than me reponding, I'm struggling, tbh :( Sorry.

Comment: Might be an idea to try and sort out the mysql stuff before doing too much on the graphics side. I say that because I was going to suggest doing a system repair as here... https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair and/or here... http://www.howtogeek.com/196740/how-to-fix-an-ubuntu-system-when-it-wont-boot/ might also reset something in your mysql stuff and, as I understand it, that's the most important bit, right?

Comment: Yes that is what I had meant - logging in after resetting root password. Anyway here is the latest update - the graphics issue is solved.  I believe it was an issue with Intel drivers being out of date and not supported for 14.04, therefore upgrade to 15.04 is needed. I say "believe" because I am not sure since my upgrade to 15.04 had gotten corrupted last night (talk about bad luck). I ended up doing a fresh install after backing up all my data.  Graphics are now back to normal.  I've reinstalled mysql and am now trying to change the data directory so it can read all my old databases.